# How to change css class from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, navigation

Suppose I want to dynamically via javascript or jquery change the class of the following to class="active" How do I achieve it?

```
<!-- Navigator -->
<div style="position: abolute; top: 50px" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul id="yw0" class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" style="color: black">Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black" class="link"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>&nbspFAQs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black" class="link"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>&nbspHelp Center</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbspPress</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>&nbspContact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to actually know how can I change the class of the li tag?

```
<li class="active">
```

I know that there is a method that I can use http://api.jquery.com/addclass/
But how do I do it with my example above.

Comment: Which `li` tag, and under what event do you want this to happen?

Comment: every element has a className attribute. so, document,getElementById("someID").className = "new class";

Comment: There is good explanation of this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/1560199) should be able to answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your expected behaviour, you could delegate event to UL element for using following logic on LI click:

```
$("#yw0").on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function () {
    $(this).add('li.active').toggleClass('active');
});
```

### -DEMO-

```js
$(function () {
    $("#yw0").on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function () {
        $(this).add('li.active').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
li.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: abolute; top: 50px" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul id="yw0" class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" style="color: black">Company</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black" class="link"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>&nbspFAQs</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black" class="link"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>&nbspHelp Center</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbspPress</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black">Careers</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: black" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>&nbspContact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted.. however I tried the snippet in my code.. the onclick function doesnot call but yes thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

For Adding class in any HTML Element

```
$("#id_of_element, .class_of_element, directly_name_of_element").addClass('active');
```

For Removing class from any HTML Element

```
$("#id_of_element, .class_of_element, directly_name_of_element").removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

In JQuery.

```
 $("li").addClass("active");
```

You will need a better selector for getting the li you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").addClass("active");
```

And in your CSS just have

```
.active {
    background: red;
}
```

Although your best bet is to know which is active and just append that class to the li tag on the respective page, assuming you're talking about navigation: for example, on your help-center.html, just add

```
 <li class="active"> rather than <li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes easily with jquery using [add class](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/), and remove with, yep you guessed it, [remove class](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

If you want to change a class, simple remove the old one and add the new

```
$('#something').removeClass.('oldClass').addClass('newClass');
```

N.b. links are to jquery docs

Answer (score 0):

Below code will add the class to the last li..

```
$(document.ready(function() {
     $('.container li:last-child').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

To select an item by class:

```
$('.active').addClass('.non-active');
$('.active').removeClass('.active');
```

To select an item by type:

```
$('li').addClass('.non-active');
$('ii').removeClass('.active');
```

To select an item by id:

```
$('#some_id').addClass('.non-active');
$('#some_id').removeClass('.active');
```

Comment: Remove the dots. When you call `addClass` or `removeClass`, you just write `$(...).addClass('active');`. And if you want to make it shorter, you can also write `$(...).toggleClass('active non-active');`

Comment: I wasn't sure about toggle class, the example jquery's site gives made it seem a little more confusing for someone who is asking a question like this.  Do you thing $(...).addClass('someclass').removeClass('newclasss);  would work?